# Closed Loops inside a Circuit and Kirchhoff's Laws

Tags: electric-circuits

Good afternoon!

I'm currently taking a physics course, and we're covering Kirchoff's Laws.  To the best of my knowledge, Kirchoff's voltage law reads "The sum of the potential differences across all the elements around any closed circuit loop must be zero."

I had a homework problem that involved the following circuit:

[image: circuit from homework problem]

I was tasked with (among other things) finding the current in the top-most branch of the circuit (between A and B).  While trying to find that, I was faced with applying Kirchhoff's Voltage Law to loop CBDC.  In a situation like this, how can the voltage changes across the individual elements in the loop sum to zero?

More generally, in a circuit consisting of two batteries of different voltages and no resistors, how can the sum of the potential changes across the elements be zero?

Thank you!

Comment: The connection between node $C$ and node $D$ renders any calculation based on Kirchhoff's laws meaningless unless one or both of the batteries had an internal resistance.

Comment: This circuit, as presented, is as much a logical contradiction as a formula saying $4.5\ V=5.6\ V$. You'll have to ask your instructor what they want you to do with logically impossible circuits.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Ajay Reddy! Note that, as drawn, the nodes labelled C & D *are the same node*, i.e., you have drawn a 4. 5 V (ideal) voltage source in parallel with a 5.6 V (ideal) voltage source. Did you mean to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!  I figured out what was going on in that problem.  There was a voltmeter connecting points C and D, but not a wired connection.  In the homework's provided schematic the voltmeter connections were drawn in the same fashion as a wired connection, which caused me some confusion.  I appreciate all your assistance!